# RavenDB Spatial Filter

Tags: ravendb

Help with Understanding RavenDB query, I'm using following model to store & index spatial data.

```
public class GeoRecord {
 public string SearchId {get; set;}
 public string Tag {get; set;}
 public double Latitude {get; set;}
 public double Longitude {get; set;}
}


public class GeoRecord_GeoIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<GeoRecord>
    {
        public GeoRecord_GeoIndex()
        {
            Map = records => from @record in records
                select new
                {
                    IndexName = "geoIndex",
                    record.SearchId,
                    Coordinates = CreateSpatialField(@record.Latitude, @record.Longitude)
                };
        }
    }
```

I can able to filter all GeoRecord's using Spatial query like below:

```
await session
    .Query<GeoRecord, GeoRecord_GeoIndex>()
    .Spatial("Coordinates", factory => factory.Within(shapeWkt: wkt))
    .ToListAsync();
```

However I would like to filter by both SearchId & Coordinates, I got this solution however I would like to understand if it uses GeoRecord_GeoIndex rather than filtering the results from GeoRecord.

```
await session.Advanced.AsyncDocumentQuery<GeoRecord, GeoRecord_GeoIndex>()
                .WhereIn("SearchId", activeSearchIds)
                .Intersect()
                .Spatial("Coordinates", criteria => criteria.Within(shapeWkt:wkt))
                .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are querying index `GeoRecord_GeoIndex`, and it is the one used to filter.

A **static index** contains:

1. A list of indexed terms for each index-field specified in the Map function,
   (your index-fields are: IndexName, SearchId & Coordinates)
2. A mapping to the relevant document

At query time, the indexed terms are filtered according to your query and the relevant documents are fetched from the database

some link to demo:
https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/static-indexes/map-index#step-3